# Running sampler of jmeter in isolation

Tags: jmeter

Suppose my threads are 30 and iteration count is 1 and I have samplers such as:

```
sampler1
sampler2
sampler3
....
sampler10
```

Whenever I run the test plan with corresponding ramp up period some of my samplers are being executed concurrently I meant user 1 is executing sampler1 and also user 20 is executing same sampler which is absolutely fine but I want `sampler3` to be executed in isolation i.e. when that sampler is being executed by someone no other user should try to access it.

Is there any way?

I am using Jmeter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion is make another thread group and create testplan with sampler3. JMeter also provides  option to run thread groups consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) guide you can put your `Sampler 3` under [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

From documentation

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.